# Why is Bob's name called four times in Project Mayhem?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

In [*Fight Club*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club), there are no names in Project Mayhem. Despite this, Bob's name is called four times - is it something to do with the plot or did I miss something?

Answer (score 7):

In Project Mayhem there are no rules, no names, no questions. But there are rules in fact.

Everything Tyler says is fact. He said, "There are no names in Project Mayhem". After that he says (we see him as the Narrator) "His name was Robert Paulsen".

The members of P. M. are confused with this paradox, and trying to build in their "religion" or "mindset". They see this as a kind of revelation, and see this as a rule-like something.

**EDIT**

The 4 times has no importance, they just keep it repeating to try to understand and give a significant abstract meaning for that. They follow Tyler as a messiah, take care all of his words.

Comment: So............?

Comment: sorry, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Okay, fine enough.

Comment: Don't they say something like „Ah, I get it. Once you die, you have a name again.“? You should include that part in the answer.

Comment: The "trying to build in their "religion" or "mindset"." and "try to understand and give a significant abstract meaning for that." sentences refers it I guess, I though it would unnessesery to quote the dialogues too

Comment: @TamásJuhász Well, it gives your points a little more significance. I also missed this line when reading the answer.

Comment: @TamásJuhász It always helps to back up your theory with facts. :)

Comment: It has no mention in the book about the four times, I made the theory referring to this fact.

Answer (score 5):

Tyler Durden (Brad Pitt) was the person who invented Project Mayhem.  Tyler was the person who says there are no names in Project Mayhem.

The Narrator (Edward Norton) is not aware at this point that he is also Tyler Durden.  He's not (consciously) of the same mindset.  When Bob dies, he still has the human element of wanting to ensure Bob's life (and death) has meaning, so he reminds the members of PM that Bob has a name.  He is a person.

The members of PM become confused, because (from what they know) Tyler Durden is first telling them that PM members have no name, and then that Bob does, in fact, have a name.  These guys are trained to be drones, so they basically regurgitate whatever they're told.  They chant "His name is Robert Paulsen" believing Tyler *wants* them to acknowledge Bob, and that PM members receive names when they die.

If I'm not mistaken, they actually chant this many times over, and not just 4 times.